# typescript - Type '{ value: number; date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'Record[]'. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I'm adding a object to an array as below:

"type '{ value: number; date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'Record[]'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'value' does not exist in type 'Record[]'. ts(2322)"

```
export interface Record {
  value: number
  date: Date
}

const transaction: Record[] = {
  value: amount.value,
  date: new Date()
}


// transaction
{ value: 50.00, date: 2020-08-04T11:52:28.876Z },
{ value: 13.10, date: 2020-08-04T11:57:32.900Z }
```

Comment: `Record[]` is an array of Record objects, not a Record object by itself, either change the type to `Record` or but `[` and `]` around your object

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to save an object but the waiting type is an array of objects.